# How do I push a Julia array to the garbage collector in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, garbage-collection, julia

On https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/embedding/ it says how to use Julia arrays and the garbage collector in C, but not how to use them together.

Let's say, I allocated an array in the following manner as it says in the example:

```
jl_value_t* array_type = jl_apply_array_type((jl_value_t*)jl_float64_type, 1);
jl_array_t* x          = jl_alloc_array_1d(array_type, 10);
double *xData          = (double*)jl_array_data(x);
```

If I do not use the array in the next call to a `jl_` function, it will be garbage collected, as evidenced by it giving me a garbage value. If I (a) use `jl_gc_enable(0)` or (b) use the array in Julia in the next call, I do not have any issues.

I could push the array to the garbage collector, but the example code below is not helping me:

```
jl_value_t **args;
JL_GC_PUSHARGS(args, 2); // args can now hold 2 `jl_value_t*` objects
args[0] = some_value;
args[1] = some_other_value;
// Do something with args (e.g. call jl_... functions)
JL_GC_POP();
```

This code requires a `jl_value_t**`, but I don't have such an array. I only have the `array_type`, `x` and `xData`, which are all three of a different type.

So how would I go about pushing the array so that it does not get garbage collected?

Comment: Can't you just typecast `args[0] = (jl_array_t* )x` this way?

Comment: @kiranBiradar No, I get a `ReadOnlyMemoryError`

Comment: Sorry (jl_value_t*)x try his one

Comment: Yeah I know, the other one wouldn't even compile :)

Comment: Just a guess, but, in the doc, a cheap workaround from the "Working with Arrays" section. Do your own `malloc` and call `jl_ptr_to_array_1d`. If the 4th arg is 0, the data is unmanaged by GC?

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah, I'll try that again. Got something wrong last time